# Time consuming Tensorflow's CUDA driver check in AWS Lambda

Tags: tensorflow, aws-lambda

I've been running an AWS Lambda and mounted an EFS, where I've installed Tensorflow 2.4. When I try to run the Lambda (and every Lambda that uses Tensorflow 2.4) it wastes a lot of time (about 4 minutes, or maybe more sometimes) on some Tensorflow's settings check. So I need to set a very wide timeout to overcome this issue.

These are the prints that the Lambda produces:

1. 2022-05-17 06:33:21.917336: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2. 2022-05-17 06:33:21.921992: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /var/lang/lib:/lib64:/usr/lib64:/var/runtime:/var/runtime/lib:/var/task:/var/task/lib:/opt/lib
3. 2022-05-17 06:33:21.922025: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:326] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
4. 2022-05-17 06:33:21.922048: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (169.254.137.137): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
5. 2022-05-17 06:33:21.922460: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
6. 2022-05-17 06:33:22.339905: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
7. 2022-05-17 06:33:22.340468: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:112] CPU Frequency: 2500010000 Hz
8. [WARNING]    2022-05-17T06:33:22.436Z    c4500036-5b77-4808-a062-f8ae820b0317    AutoGraph could not transform <function Model.make_predict_function..predict_function at 0x7f65bfb37280> and will run it as-is.
   Please report this to the TensorFlow team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output.
   Cause: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
   To silence this warning, decorate the function with @tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert

What I need is to overcome this waste of time, and run a clean elaboration.

Comment: Your environment does not find the CUDA libraries, might it be that inference on CPU just takes way more time?

Comment: Yes, now I checked and it just a 'time-consuming' job. There's no problem connected to Tensorflow or any ML library